# Stripe payment bancontact

Tags: wordpress, stripe, civicrm-event

I tried to configure stripe as payment processor for my events in civicrm.
But I can only see the credit card option...
Actually, credit cards, are the only option I can see. Other payment methods aren't show.

I looked already in the documentation, but can't find any helpful thing...
Does someone have some instructions I can check why there aren't loading other payment methods? Or do you have a link to some good documentation?

Thank you!

Comment: When I check my logging in the browser I get also `No available paymentMethods for paymentRequest`. But my payment methods are active in stripe? Is there an other way how I can config the payment methods?

Comment: What "other payment methods" are you hoping to use?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I would like something like creditcards, bancontact and sofort. When I just add stripe, then I see a field to add my credit card and when I fill in a test card number I get the logs in stripe. So I think it can communicate with each other. But then I try to create bancontact or sofort, but It shows te same field... and in the browser log it's also " No available paymentMethods for paymentRequest"...  So I think there's some misconfiguration...  But I'm a bit lost in the documentation...

https://paste.pics/3609e7353eab2d9d05e7eb5a0b2e60f1

Comment: other screenshot: https://paste.pics/60006768d83f558c06159be8ef9884ad

Comment: Does the CiviCRM Stripe extension suggest these options are available?

Comment: Yes. Bancontact is a debit card.

From CiviCRM Stripe documentation: `Currently one-off and recurring payments by Credit/Debit card are supported.`

Comment: Stripe does support bancontact but not the Civicrm extension. Check the roadmap of planned features to have an estimate if you want to sponsor this -> https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/blob/master/docs/roadmap.md#user-content-bancontact